# Easiest way to terminate function in C++

Tags: c++, error-handling, terminate

I am wondering what the easiest or the most convenient way to terminate a function in C++.

For example I have `int function()` and I want it to do nothing (somewhat like void) under certain condition in the function, but I don't want the whole program to terminate. So, no "exit" please :D .

I saw people use `return;`, but I am not sure if it's safe.

Hope you can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with `return` can you come back.

Or you could `throw` an exception.

In both cases you need to be aware to handle the needed resource deallocations.

Comment: Resource deallocations should always be handled by destructors, so they are guaranteed to occur regardless of flow.

Comment: @Potatoswatter It is not always in C++, only the local variables will be automatically destructed.

Comment: @Potatoswatter That almost sounds like "don't worry about resources", I'd prefer to advise "always use RAII to allocate/deallocate resources, so that it is safe to leave the function by return or exception".

Comment: @polkadotcadaver RAII is identical to using destructors to deallocate.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Then declare a local object of a new type with an appropriate destructor.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm aware of that, I'm only commenting on emphasis and readability :)

Comment: @polkadotcadaver Using an opaque acronym is more readable? Anyone who has already heard of RAII is unlikely to need the advice.

Comment: haha. I'm sure they could look it up if they haven't heard of it.

Comment: "Yes, with return can you come back." -- Are you really suggesting that `return;` inside a function whose signature is `int func()` is a good idea? Do you know that it's undefined behavior?

Comment: @Jefffrey No. I suggested only `return`, and said nothing about its  parameter.

Comment: @Jefffrey Going off the end of the function is UB. `return;` is illegal, and since it's the gist of the question, this answer seems incomplete.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, Oh yeah. Apparently (as of paragraph 2 of 6.6.3 of the standard) you a right. Thanks for FTFM.

Answer (score 3):

Inside a function declared `int function()` you can always return some value e.g. with `return 0;` -at any time and at any place inside the function body.

You could also go outside a function by throwing an [exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling), this is a non-local [control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow) transfer.

In practice, you throw some exception, e.g.

```
 throw std::runtime_error("something bad");
```

then some function still active in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) should `catch` that exception. So perhaps your `main` contains

```
 try {
    do_the_job(something);
 } 
 catch (std::runtime_error err) {
    std::cerr << "bad thing happened:" << err.what() << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

and `do_the_job` called `foo` which called `bar` which called your `function` which `throw` the exception which is caught in `main`, etc... (the destructors of local values on the call stack get called).

Answer (score 3):

You need to either supply a return value, or `throw` an exception. If control flow returns to the caller as normal, then just `return 0;`. But this suggests an organizational problem.

`return` with no value is only allowed for functions returning `void`.

Answer (score 3):

If your function has return type `int`, then if you return at all you need to return a value, not just `return;`.

The return value of your function probably has some meaning to the caller. So one of three situations applies:

1) There is some integer value available that doesn't mean "I did something". So you can document that value means "I didn't do anything", and return it. `0` and `-1` are generally the values most likely to be usable for this, but it depends entirely on what the function does and what the return value means.

2) There is no value available that doesn't mean "I did something", so the function cannot return a value to say "I did nothing". Then you could change the signature of the function to give it a means to indicate whether it did anything -- for example return a `pair<bool,int>` instead of just an `int`, with one value to indicate success/failure and another which is meaningful on success but not on failure. Or you could add an `int &` parameter to `function` in which you will store the value currently used as the return value, and change the return type to a `bool` which simply indicates success or failure. Alternatively if the situation in question is one where the function cannot carry out the operation it's designed for then you can throw an exception (and document what the function might throw).

In both of the above cases, existing code that calls the function may have to be updated (and certainly will if you change the signature). This leads to the third situtation:

3) there is no means for the function to indicate it did nothing, *and* you're not allowed to change the interface of the function (for example perhaps it's already documented not to throw and you don't want to change a fact that existing callers are relying on). Then I'm afraid you're in the situation you didn't want. If a function finds that it cannot satisfy its contractual obligations even by throwing, then all you can do is `terminate` or `exit`. The program cannot continue, because the caller has every right to expect that the function will do "something" but you cannot do it. This usually indicates that the design is somehow wrong, or that you're implementing an interface that simply isn't flexible enough to support what you're planning.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways, in C++, for a function to end:

- `return` a suitable value
- `throw` an exception
- `std::terminate` the program

It is up to you, the programmer, to decide how to handle the situation you are in. Generally speaking, you find yourself in two situations:

- technical error: corrupted state, violation of prerequisites, is generally handled either by calling `std::terminate` or `throw`
- functional situation: given the argument, there is no result (for example a `search` may fail), is generally handled by either calling `throw` or returning a sentinel value.

So, since in your case it looks like we are talking about a functional situation, you may ask yourself if this situation is *an error* on the part of the caller (in which case an exception is a good candidate) or if this is a normal situation (such as the `search` not finding anything) in which case a sentinel value is probably best.

For sentinel values, I have seen some methods:

- C-ish: return a pointer (and use `nullptr` as Sentinel), can be a smart-pointer if necessary
- Object-ish: have a Null object of this kind
- Boolean folly: take the "return argument" by reference and return a boolean to indicate whether you wrote to it or not
- Functional-ish: return a `boost::optional<Type>` (and use `boost::none` as Sentinel)

There are, really, plenty of schemes to choose from; I would recommend the latter if you return a copy and the pointer one if you return a handle to a pre-existing object.

Comment: +1, might also note that `terminate` is suitable when the precondition for a destructor has been violated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using `return` might run you into some trouble, since the compiler requires you actually return a value, and anyone reasonable would expect so when reading your prototype. The best approach for your case would be to `throw` an exception.

**EDIT:** I have been reminded below that, yes, exceptions should only be thrown in case of an unrecoverable error. Perhaps a simple `return` is the fastest approach. But the correct behavior you should have is to raise an error flag of some kind when your condition is met.

Comment: In  a  void function  you  need not give return a  value.

Comment: It's true that he needs to return an integer, and that its value should make sense to users of the function, but exceptions should only be thrown if the reason to exit the method is that there has been an unrecoverable error.

Comment: @PeterHorvath "For example I have int function()"